# Typescript value checking

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function like this:

```
  private myFunc = (myNumber: number) => {
    if (myNumber === 1) {
        console.log('here');
    }
  }
```

Where myNumber is 1, I don't get the console output. From having a look at the console, I can see that myNumber is being treated as a different type (string). Changing the code like this works:

```
  private myFunc = (myNumber: number) => {
    if (myNumber == 1) {
        console.log('here');
    }
  }
```

I was under the impression that Typescript would issue a 'compile' error in this case, but it doesn't seem to. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please show how the function is getting called.

Comment: The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Typescript would show a compile time error if you'd do:

```
 myFunc("1");
```

However, as you seem to call it at runtime, Typescript can't check for it.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript use a static type checking ( typescript is not present at the runtime ) so if you pass a string to the function 'myNumber' will be a string. You need to add your own check inside the function

```
  private myFunc = (myNumber: number) => {
    if (parseInt(myNumber) === 1) {
        console.log('here');
    }
  }
```